# Return values with call() or apply() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the function's return value when it's called from call() or apply()?

My scenario:

I have a function that works fine with `apply()` function. On object contructor:

```
var someObject = new SomeObject({NameFunction: "MakeNames"});
```

On a loop in the object's method:

```
var name = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    name = window[this.NameFunction].apply(null, [data[i]]);
}
```

And the `MakeNames` function:

```
function MakeNames(data)
{
    return data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName;
}
```

That var `name` stay empty cause `apply` doesn't return any value from the function. Note that I'm sure the function is called and the argument is passed succesfully. Please don't tell me to use `name = MakeNames(data[i]);` directly, because it is obvious that I don't want this solution.

It doesn't matter if it is `apply`, `call` or whatever JavaScript has to make this work, if works.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: return values work ok for me. running this in the browser console `var x = "huh".toString.apply("test");` set x to "test" for me.

Comment: apply and call will return values. Something else must be wrong. can you supply more of the code that exposed the function you're trying to call? Also what is toString doing? your function name is already a string in your example.

Comment: @ben336 Sorry dude, can't understand your point. Can you post a more accurate answer?

Comment: @Tim disconsider that toString(). I removed it and the result stays the same.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown My answer is very accurate :) As is the other comment and RobG's answer.  The point is that call and apply don't prevent you from returning a value.  Your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown consider it disconsidered. The answer lies in something you've not posted. For example, if you haven't set the NameFunction property in your constructor.

Comment: @ben336 sorry again man, I do not understood it. I confess I'm still don't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result of:

```
window[this.NameFunction.toString()].apply(null, [data[i]])
```

is **exactly the same** as:

```
MakeNames(data[i])
```

since the only difference is the value of *this* in the *MakeNames* function, and since *this* isn't used, it can't make any difference. The use of *apply* doesn't change whether the function returns a value or not, or what the value is.

Whatever issue you have, it isn't in the (bits of) posted code.

Comment: God damn you're right. This code is ok, the problem is outside of it. Shame on me. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code where `data` is set, or where `data[i]` would be an object that has the properties `FirstName` and `LastName`. Try a fail-over:

```
function MakeNames(data) {
    return (data.hasOwnProperty('FirstName')) ? data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName : 'John Doe';
}
```